# HTML figure with both caption and notes

Tags: html, css

I would like to include a figure in a HTML document. This figure needs to have a title/caption (above) and some reading notes (below). This is the HTML equivalent of [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56529/note-below-figure) based on `latex`.

I know how to add a title to a Figure using `figcaption`:

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Wikipedia logo</figcaption>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Wikipedia_logo_%28svg%29.svg">
</figure>
```

How can I add some reading notes below ?

Comment: use the `<p>` tag in your `<figure>`?

Comment: Or use the `<p>` outside the `<figure>` and set a `<div>` as a parent from the `<figure>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a paragraph inside the figure.

Permitted content of a `figure` includes "flow content" which allows a `p`

> A `<figcaption`> element, followed by flow content; or flow content followed by a `<figcaption>` element; or flow content.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure)

```css
img {
max-width:100%;
}

figure {
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <figcaption>Wikipedia logo</figcaption>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Wikipedia_logo_%28svg%29.svg">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</figure>
```